# ArcMap Way to merge two shapefiles and take the average of their polygons that overlap?

Tags: arcmap, polygon, merge, overlapping-features, union

So I have two shapefiles that show storm surge height values for two different areas. Nevertheless, they overlap for a good portion of their areas. When I merge them together, it seems that the polygons in the overlap area default to showing the maximum height.

Is there a way for them to instead average together so the overlap can be an average of polygons from the different shapefiles rather than the maximum values?

Comment: what software are you using?

Comment: ArcMap 10.6. I also can load the data using ArcGIS Pro if that has more capabilities for something like this.

Comment: when merging there should be an option to select average

Comment: @neogeomat do you know where? It might be in the field map part but I haven't seemed to locate it.

Comment: Please check these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949926/shapefile-with-overlapping-polygons-calculate-average-values)

Comment: I assume when you say merge you mean something else? Whats the tool you want to use?

Comment: @JamesPatrick I guess I meant any tool. Ended up figuring it out using the union tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

I ended up performing a union on the two layers. Then I added a new field, selected only the polygons that overlapped, and performed a field calculator averaging the height values from the two separate layers on only those selected polygons.

Comment: Accept your own answer with the checkbox!